# Factorial calculation problems in C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to calculate `( x + y )! / x! * y`! but whenever I give values, program doesn't work properly. It prints wrong numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double Fact(int x) {
    double sum = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        sum *= i;
    }
    return sum;
}

void paths(int x,int y){
    cout << "There are " << Fact(x + y) / Fact(x) * Fact(y) << " different paths.";
}

int main() {
    cout << "Please enter coordiantes(x,y) to know different paths: ";
    int x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    paths(x, y);

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Comment: `(x + y)! / x! * y!` or `(x + y)! / (x! * y!)`?

Comment: No, they are not. See [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: Thank to you, I solved the problem.

Comment: A couple of comments. First, using doubles is bound to introduce inaccuracies in the process, when x! is larger than 2 to the power of however many bits there are in double's mantissa, the computer will start to approximate. On my PC 23! is already wrong. Second, calling Fact with x+y will calculate x! and y! along the way. You could cache previously calculated values in a static vector, and either return a previously calculated value if its in the cache, or pick up from the high water mark if not.

Answer (score 3):

You've apparently already solved your problem, but I'm going to posit that this probably isn't the best way to do the job.

I'd start by looking at the calculations involved in each part of the equation:

(X+Y)! -> 1 * 2 * ... * X ... * X+1 *... * (X+Y)

In particular, note that the sequence from 1..X is exactly X!

Likewise, looking at (X! * Y!), we get:

X! = 1 * 2 * ... X
Y! = 1 * 2 * ... Y

So, we can symbolically convert this to something like:

(X! * A) / (X! * B)

We can then convert that to:

X!/X! * (A/B)

...and since X!/X! is obviously 1, we're left with just A/B, which is:

((X+1) * (X+2) * ... * (X+Y)) / Y!

Especially if X and Y are sort of close together this can make the calculation quite a bit faster and more manageable.

In this manipulation, we want to choose the larger of the two inputs to treat as X. This maximizes the amount we factor out, and minimizes the work we do (but this isn't strictly necessary for the technique to work--it just helps keep the work to a minimum).

Answer (score -2):

You may use:

```
    #include <cmath>

    double Fact(const int n)
    {
      return tgamma(n + 1);
    }
```